Godot Error 'Class "Recipe" hides a global script class'

The error is repeating for all of the custom resources in my project. The recipe class is an example. I have not instantiated this as a singleton or defined this class_name anywhere else, this error constantly persists.
I tried searching it up and looking at the solutions and moving the files to a new folder and starting a new project, but neither of them worked.

Idk if this is the same case, but I have run into errors that look like this when moving scripts outside of the editor. Sometimes Godot reports that a script hides another script with the same but the other script is the same one when it was in a different path but Godot didn't register the move. That kind of error goes away by modifying the script and saving it (I would add or remove a new line so it appears modified and Godot lets me save it).
